# "Storage" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft.Xna.Framework"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I don't understand why it appears given error : The type or namespace name "Storage" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft.Xna.Framework" (assembly reference may be missing).

I try to download Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given any information to your problem such as code you have written or references added so I'm sorry if this doesn't help. But, if you're using Visual Studio 2019 [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jbld5ZrW3ls) is a video to help you add the entire framework to your program.

EDIT: If you already have the framework downloaded. What you need to do is right click your project on the right. then Add>Reference.. then search for Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage.